# Is there a way to make indexes contiguous within an IBOutletCollection?

Tags: ios, ios6, iboutletcollection

I'm currently working on a project where the buttons within an **IBOutletCollection** each represent a card in a deck of playing cards. I ran into a problem though when I was I added all 52 cards that I was getting an object out of bounds error based on the **indexOfObject** in

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
...

- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.game flipCardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender]];
    ...
}
```

When I went through all the buttons, I was finding that within the IBOutletCollection, there were some buttons that skipped an index. I was getting indexes of ...30, 31, 32, 34... so that with just 52 cards, I was still getting indexes like 54.

Even when I start over with even just a few cards, I'm seeing that it is skipping indexes.

Is there a way I could (or even should...?) manually manipulate the indexes within the Outlet Collection so that they are all contiguous? Or are these the sort of things best left untouched to find a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, dont do this kind of stuff on IBOutletCollection. I use IBOutletCollection only when i rotate device and i have different views (without autolayout) with the same buttons, so there only will be 2 indexes.

In your example you shoul use UICollectionView, good tutorial you should find there [UICollectionView tutorial](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/paul-dakessian/ios-6-tutorial-getting-started-collection-views)